# Discover random web servers and print the index page title

Tags: python, bash

[Github repo](https://github.com/Ricky-Wilson/webserver-discovery.git)

I wrote this little toy today that probes random web servers and prints out the title of their index page. I'm curious if this code is any good since I'm a bit rusty.

**get_titles.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

""" Probe random web server and print out the title of their index page. """

import os
import sys
import lxml.html


def get_title(url):
    '''Extract the title from a webpage.
    If anything goes wrong like the request
    times out or the page does not have a
    title get_title will return None'''
    try:
        title = lxml.html.parse(url)
        return title.find(".//title").text
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception:
        return None

def shell(command):
    """Run a shell command.
    return it's output as a string"""
    return os.popen(command).read()

def scan(nhosts):
    """Run an nmap scan of n hosts.
    This will return IPv4 addresses of hosts
    that are up and have a service running on
    port 80. Simply supply the number of hosts
    you would like to check."""
    results = set(shell('./discover.sh {}'.format(nhosts)).split('\n'))
    if not results:
        print 'Nothing Found.'
        sys.exit(0)
    return ["http://{}".format(ip) for ip in results if ip]

def main():
    """ Run the scan."""
    if not len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        print 'You forgot to tell me how many hosts to check'
        sys.exit(0)
    for url in scan(sys.argv[1]):
        title = get_title(url)
        if title:
            print title, url


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**discover.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

nhosts=$1

nmap \
--host-timeout 10s \
--max-retries 0 \
–min-parallelism 100 \
-T5 \
-Pn \
-n \
-iR $1 \
-p80 \
-oG tmp.txt \
--open \
tmp.txt > /dev/null

cat tmp.txt | grep 'Host' | awk '{print $2}'
rm tmp.txt
```

Comment: Minor point: `cat tmp.txt | grep 'Host'` is a  [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and can be shorted to `grep 'Host' tmp.txt` — and then the entire line can be shorted even further to `awk '/Host/ {print $2}' tmp.txt`.

Comment: As a sysadmin I wouldn't be happy with you port scanning to find webservers :)  How about selecting a random word from a large dictionary and using it as a "i feel lucky" google query (which returns top non-paid result), then parsing that page for the title....

Comment: "Run a shell command. Return **its** output as a string."

Answer (score 14):

Overall, the code is pretty clean. Some notes about the Python part:

- be consistent about the documentation string style - enclose them with triple quotes, start with an upper-case letter, end with a dot ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings)). I also think that you can use less newline breaks there.
- if we would follow [PEP8 importing recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), there should be a newline between the "system" level imports and third-parties:

  ```
  import os
  import sys

  import lxml.html
  ```
- you should have 2 line breaks between the function definitions ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines))
- use `print()` as a function for Python 3 compatibility
- I would avoid unnecessary invert of the logic and replace:

  ```
  if not len(sys.argv) >= 2:
  ```

  with:

  ```
  if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  ```
- [avoid using bare `except` clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements)
- you can use `.findtext()` method:

  ```
  title.findtext(".//title")
  ```

  which will return `None` if `title` element was not found.

Answer (score 7):

On top of what @alecxe has said I would advise you update your docstrings to include the parameters and descriptions of what they do [using some well known convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24385103/667648). Also, I would emphasize you use a well known convention so that way some documentation generator (for example, [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/)) can use the information to generate readable docs.

Note: Sphinx uses the reST convention.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the shell script portion of your project I would indent the subsequent lines of the nmap command like so:

```
nmap \
    --host-timeout 10s \
    --max-retries 0 \
    –min-parallelism 100 \
    -T5 \
    -Pn \
    -n \
    -iR $1 \
    -p80 \
    -oG tmp.txt \
    --open \
    tmp.txt > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

**get_titles.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Probe random web server and print out the title of their index page.
:param nhosts: The number of random IPs you want to probe.
"""

import os
import sys

# third party imports
import lxml.html


def get_title(url):
    """
    Extract the title from a web page..
    :param url: The URL of the page
    :returns: A string if title was found or None if somthing goes wrong
    """
    try:
        title = lxml.html.parse(url)
        return title.find(".//title").text
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception:
        return None

def shell(command):
    """
    Execute a shell command and return it's output.
    :param command: The command you want to execute
    :returns: A string representation of the commands output
    """
    return os.popen(command).read()

def scan(nhosts):
    """
    Scan for web servers.
    This function uses namp to find random systems
    that are running a service on port 80.
    We will assume that if the system is running a service
    on port 80 it's a web server and generate a URL for it.
    :param nhosts:  The number of random IPs you would like to probe
    :returns: A list if URLs
    """
    results = set(shell('./discover.sh {}'.format(nhosts)).split('\n'))
    if not results:
        print 'Nothing Found.'
        sys.exit(0)
    return ["http://{}".format(ip) for ip in results if ip]

def main():
    """
    This function puts everything together
    :returns: None
    """
    if not len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        print 'You forgot to tell me how many hosts to check'
        sys.exit(0)
    for url in scan(sys.argv[1]):
        title = get_title(url)
        if title:
            print title, url


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Diff**

---

```
@@ -1,17 +1,25 @@
  #!/usr/bin/env python

 -""" Probe random web server and print out the title of their index page. """
 +""" 
 +Probe random web server and print out the title of their index page. 
 +
 +:param nhosts: The number of random IPs you want to probe. 
 +"""

  import os
  import sys
 +
 +# third party imports
  import lxml.html


  def get_title(url):
 -    '''Extract the title from a webpage.
 -    If anything goes wrong like the request
 -    times out or the page does not have a
 -    title get_title will return None'''
 +    """
 +    Extract the title from a web page..
 +
 +    :param url: The URL of the page
 +    :returns: A string if title was found or None if somthing goes wrong
 +    """
      try:
          title = lxml.html.parse(url)
          return title.find(".//title").text
 @@ -21,24 +29,37 @@ def get_title(url):
          return None

  def shell(command):
 -    """Run a shell command.
 -    return it's output as a string"""
 +    """
 +    Execute a shell command and return it's output.
 +    
 +    :param command: The command you want to execute
 +    :returns: A string representation of the commands output
 +    """
      return os.popen(command).read()

  def scan(nhosts):
 -    """Run an nmap scan of n hosts.
 -    This will return IPv4 addresses of hosts
 -    that are up and have a service running on
 -    port 80. Simply supply the number of hosts
 -    you would like to check."""
 +    """
 +    Scan for web servers.
 +    
 +    This function uses namp to find random systems 
 +    that are running a service on port 80.
 +    We will assume that if the system is running a service
 +    on port 80 it's a web server and generate a URL for it.
 +    
 +    :param nhosts:  The number of random IPs you would like to probe
 +    :returns: A list if URLs
 +    """
      results = set(shell('./discover.sh {}'.format(nhosts)).split('\n'))
      if not results:
          print 'Nothing Found.'
          sys.exit(0)
      return ["http://{}".format(ip) for ip in results if ip]

  def main():
 -    """ Run the scan."""
 +    """  
 +    This function puts everything together    
 +    :returns: None
 +    """
      if not len(sys.argv) >= 2:
          print 'You forgot to tell me how many hosts to check'
          sys.exit(0)
```

**discover.sh**

- Removed unused variable nhosts.
- Fixed indentation.
- Shortened the parsing portion to just awk.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
nmap \
    --host-timeout 10s \
    --max-retries 0 \
    -T5 \
    -Pn \
    -n \
    -iR "$1" \
    -p80 \
    -oG tmp.txt \
    --open \
    tmp.txt > /dev/null
    awk '/Host/ {print $2}' tmp.txt
    rm tmp.txt
```

### Diff

---

```
@@ -1,19 +1,16 @@
  #!/bin/bash

 -nhosts=$1
 -
  nmap \
 ---host-timeout 10s \
 ---max-retries 0 \
 -–min-parallelism 100 \
 --T5 \
 --Pn \
 --n \
 --iR $1 \
 --p80 \
 --oG tmp.txt \
 ---open \
 -tmp.txt > /dev/null
 -
 -cat tmp.txt | grep 'Host' | awk '{print $2}'
 -rm tmp.txt 
 +    --host-timeout 10s \
 +    --max-retries 0 \
 +    –min-parallelism 100 \
 +    -T5 \
 +    -Pn \
 +    -n \
 +    -iR "$1" \
 +    -p80 \
 +    -oG tmp.txt \
 +    --open \
 +    tmp.txt > /dev/null
 +    awk '/Host/ {print $2}' tmp.txt
 +    rm tmp.txt
```

Comment: You must also provide the changes that were made.  Code-only answers still aren't allowed for self-answers.